# How to swap values with SIMD instructions?

Tags: x86, vectorization, simd, intrinsics, avx2

I want to swap 16-bit values in two 256-bit vectors A and B. The dreamy way is to find an Intrinsic instruction to do it. Unfortunately, I couldn't find and I think there is no instruction for this job. The instructions such as shuffle, permute, blend, etc. keep or destroy the values in the destination. What I'm looking for is as follows:

```
vector A : |a0|a1|a2|a3|a4|a5|a6|a7||a8|a9|a10|a11|a12|a13|a14|a15|
Vector B : |b0|b1|b2|b3|b4|b5|b6|b7||b8|b9|b10|b11|b12|b13|b14|b15|
//After swapping
Vector A : |a0|a1|b2|a3|a4|b5|a6|a7||b8|a9|a10|b11|a12|a13|b14|a15|
Vector B : |b0|b1|a2|b3|b4|a5|b6|b7||a8|b9|b10|a11|b12|b13|a14|b15|
```

So the question is: what is the fastest way to swap two vectors while there are many shuffle instructions?

I have implemented the following program:

```c
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void printVeci16(__m256i vec)
{
    unsigned short int tempi16[16];
    _mm256_store_si256((__m256i *)&tempi16[0], vec);
    printf("[0]=%2u, [1]=%2u, [2]=%2u, [3]=%2u, [4]=%2u, [5]=%2u, [6]=%2u, [7]=%2u,... [8]=%2u, [9]=%2u, [10]=%2u, [11]=%2u, [12]=%2u, [13]=%2u, [14]=%2u, [15]=%2u \n\n",
     tempi16[0],tempi16[1],tempi16[2],tempi16[3],tempi16[4],tempi16[5],tempi16[6], tempi16[7],tempi16[8],tempi16[9],tempi16[10],tempi16[11],tempi16[12],tempi16[13],tempi16[14],tempi16[15] ) ;

}

int main()
{
    short x[16], y[16];
    __m256i a,  b, temp_a, temp_b;
    __m256i mask = _mm256_set_epi8( 0,0, 0x80,0x80, 0,0, 0,0, 0x80,0x80, 0,0, 0,0       ,0x80,0x80, 0,0, 0,0, 0x80,0x80, 0,0, 0,0, 0x80,0x80, 0,0, 0,0);

    for(int i=0; i<16; i++) {x[i] = i+1; y[i] = i+17;} // make some values for vectors

    a =  _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)x); 
    b = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)y);

    printf(" original    a : "); printVeci16(a); 
    printf(" original    b : "); printVeci16(b); 

    temp_a = _mm256_blendv_epi8 (a, b, mask);
    temp_b = _mm256_blendv_epi8 (b, a, mask);

    a = temp_a;
    b = temp_b;

    printf("swap         a : ");printVeci16(a); 
    printf("swap         b : ");printVeci16(b); 

    return 0;


}
```

and the out put is here :

```
original     a : [0]= 1, [1]= 2, [2]= 3, [3]= 4, [4]= 5, [5]= 6, [6]= 7, [7]= 8,... [8]= 9, [9]=10, [10]=11, [11]=12, [12]=13, [13]=14, [14]=15, [15]=16 

original     b : [0]=17, [1]=18, [2]=19, [3]=20, [4]=21, [5]=22, [6]=23, [7]=24,... [8]=25, [9]=26, [10]=27, [11]=28, [12]=29, [13]=30, [14]=31, [15]=32 

swap         a : [0]= 1, [1]= 2, [2]=19, [3]= 4, [4]= 5, [5]=22, [6]= 7, [7]= 8,... [8]=25, [9]=10, [10]=11, [11]=28, [12]=13, [13]=14, [14]=31, [15]=16 

swap         b : [0]=17, [1]=18, [2]= 3, [3]=20, [4]=21, [5]= 6, [6]=23, [7]=24,... [8]= 9, [9]=26, [10]=27, [11]=12, [12]=29, [13]=30, [14]=15, [15]=32
```

It seems OK, but what about swapping different elements? 
For example:

```
 vector A : |a0|a1|a2|a3|a4|a5|a6|a7||a8|a9|a10|a11|a12|a13|a14|a15|
 Vector B : |b0|b1|b2|b3|b4|b5|b6|b7||b8|b9|b10|b11|b12|b13|b14|b15|
 //After swapping
 Vector A : |a0|b0|a2|a3|b3|a5|a6|b6||a8|a9 |b9 |a11|a12|b12|a14|a15|
 Vector B : |a1|b1|b2|a4|b4|b5|a7|b7||b8|a10|b10|b11|a13|b13|b14|b15|
```

It needs another implementation? Is there any general way to swap better?

I wanted to generalize this operation with an inline function. But the body is empty and need some suggestions.

```c
inline _mm256_swap_epi16( __m256i a, __m256i b, __m256i mask)
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact you perform two operations (shuffle and swap). So I can suggest next solution:

```
inline void _mm256_shuffle_swap_epi16(__m256i & a, __m256i & b, 
    const __m256i & shuffle, const  __m256i & swap)
{
    __m256i a_shuffled = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(a, shuffle);
    __m256i b_shuffled = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(b, shuffle);
    a = _mm256_blendv_epi8(a_shuffled, b_shuffled, swap);
    b = _mm256_blendv_epi8(b_shuffled, a_shuffled, swap);
}
```

If you need to shuffle values inside all length of 256-bit vector I would recomend to use next function instead of _mm256_shuffle_epi8() :

```
const __m256i K0 = _mm256_setr_epi8(
    0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70,
    0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0);

const __m256i K1 = _mm256_setr_epi8(
    0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0,
    0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70, 0x70);

inline const __m256i Shuffle(const __m256i & value, const __m256i & shuffle)
{
    return _mm256_or_si256(_mm256_shuffle_epi8(value, _mm256_add_epi8(shuffle, K0)), 
        _mm256_shuffle_epi8(_mm256_permute4x64_epi64(value, 0x4E), _mm256_add_epi8(shuffle, K1)));
}
```

Comment: The 256 bit wide cross lane `epi8` shuffle `Shuffle` is great!